# Java - under which circumstances may a JVM abruptly crash?

Tags: java, unix, process, jvm, daemon

I'm running a daemon java process on my ubuntu machine :

```
java -cp (...) &> err.log&
```

The process runs for a random period of time and then just disappears. Nothing in LOGs, err.log, no JVM crash file created (hs_err_*.log), nothing. My two questions are :

1) Under which circumstances can a java process abruptly finish ?

2) IS there any way to know what happened to the process (knowing PID) ? Does UNIX keep information about finished processes somehow ?

Comment: Have you tried running JConsole? It gives some useful information which may help.

Comment: Are you sure it's crashing and not just exiting normally?

Comment: Is there a way where you can add a stacktrace when your app exits ?

Comment: Cosmic rays could flip a dangerous bit on non-ECC memory :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1) Under which circumstances can a java process abruptly finish ?***

When it exits by its own but I guess you ruled out that or when it is killed with SIGKILL. This might be the oom killer if you are on Linux. Did you look at the system message logs ?

***2) IS there any way to know what happened to the process (knowing PID) ?***

Generally not unless you configure some tracing tools to get that information

***Does UNIX keep information about finished processes somehow ?***

No, but depending on the Unix variant you are using, that might be something simple to add.
In your example, you can just print the process exit status with `echo $?`

If it is `265`, that would mean the process was killed with signal 9 (`=265-256`).

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple shell script that somehow alerts me when the JVM terminated. Perhaps send an email with the JVM's exit code.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Launch JVM and wait...
java -cp ...

# do something with the exit code $?
# log it to a file or mail it yourself
```

Perhaps, the exit code might reveal something.

Answer (score 0):

I would run it as a daemon with [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net) as it allows several ways to monitor the memory etc, has restart options, and you can also enable log on the wrapper process so you can have much info when there is an issue.